# Java 8 - Java FX Exception when App starts

Tags: java, javafx

Stack Technology:
Java 8 and Java FX

Hi, I'm building a JAR to keep running as background service in my server to upload files to another server. It's just a jar without interface.

It's used `javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService` to execute my jobs.

But when I call `javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService.start()` the app throws an wierd exception.

## Exception

```
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_es2.so: libXxf86vm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
        at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$464(ES2Pipeline.java:68)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:50)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6ec1d3cf68, pid=16996, tid=140113268762368
```

The question it's, what this means?

1. Another lib?
2. Graphic drivers? But it's at DigitalOcean (Ubuntu Version)
3. The app execute without problems in my Windows and Ubuntu local machine, both have graphic drivers installed.
4. This just happends when I execute the app in DigitalOcean Server.
5. There's compatibility problem's with Java 8/Java FX on linux?

All the best.

Comment: The .so libraries are what the jvm leans on for C compiled code.  My guess is that you have a corrupt installation of jvm.  It's either missing some required files or the file itself is corrupted.  But then I can't say for sure, it has never happened to me.

Comment: If you don't have an interface, why are you using `javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService`? That requires the FX Application Thread to be started, which in turn requires the FX toolkit. If there's no UI, this seems pretty redundant. I'm not entirely sure why you're getting the error, but it's probably because you're trying to start the FX toolkit on a system that doesn't have the appropriate graphical support. Would a `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` not work for what you need?